# Display image instead of text in Calendar "NextPrev"

Tags: asp.net, calendar, asp.net-3.5

How can I display an image instead of '<' or '>' for the ASP.NET `Calendar`?

I've tried the following, but it won't display (and also seems a bit messy):

```
cal.PrevMonthText = "<img src='/Style/images/calanderright.png' alt='Previous' />"
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is your image actually named "calanderright.png" or was that a typo for calendar?

Comment: Yes it is, and its nothing to do with me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this](http://help.syncfusion.com/ug_92/User%20Interface/ASP.NET/Tools/default.htm?turl=Documents/517232customizingcalendarappearancethroughcss.htm) link out, I think it could help you. It would have to be done through CSS, because the control itself has very little customization for NextPrevStyle property.

Comment: did you get it to work with your image? It seems like that should work, but I didn't actually try it myself. I'm curious if it worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use image instead of text in `PrevMonthText` property like

```
PrevMonthText="<img src='../Images/previous.gif' border='0'>"
```